# How to get array from firebase cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: firestore screenshot]

I am lost as to how to retrieve the values from a firebase snapshot document like the one shown in the image. Within each field are contained three values. When it is processed, I should have three different key/value pairs. Example (exchangeRate = 560, exchangeRate = 400, exchangeRate = 450). When processed, this will apply to the other fields.

Comment: the object will return you a data list so you can iterate and get the values from the list.

Comment: I have seen the array list it returned. I am not able to process it. Could you show me how please?

Comment: Can you explain you got the int list. then what do you want to do?

Comment: AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(ConnectionState.done, Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot', null, null)
[USD/NGN]
[560, 400, 450]
[830422, 271618, 515185]
[BUY, SELL]
[Timestamp(seconds=1665391246, nanoseconds=415000000), Timestamp(seconds=1665391318, nanoseconds=455000000),
Timestamp(seconds=1665391429, nanoseconds=891000000)]
[true]
[75000, 2500, 11500]
Application finished.

Comment: show me the code.

Comment: if you are seeking help you should show the code you have tried so we can check what's wrong. or else, no one would waste time for this trying to guess what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can access the **array** from **firestore**.

```
   DocumentSnapshot document = getOrdersResult();
   List<int> group = (List<int>) document.get("exchangeRate");
```